Aluminum electrolytic capacitors energize question
I have stored here electronic devices with aluminum electrolytic capacitors used and manufactured in the early 90s. Here the temperature varies between 33-36C RH: 57-67% without rain in my home. These electronic devices need to be energized what maximum interval time for energize all electronics in 220v to prevent failures in these aluminum electrolytic capacitors caused by disuse?
I know that these aluminum electrolytic capacitors and electronic devices are old and I can't do anything to make them look like new again with factory specifications and open all the electronic devices, desolder all the aluminum electrolytic capacitors, reform them, resolder these capacitors, close the devices is complex and careful work I would just like to keep them in their current state for as long as possible because electronic devices work normally today but I read that if they remain unused for many years when turned on they can have serious problems so I would like to find the maximum interval to energize these devices for 30 minutes to 1 hour for prevents fails in aluminium electrolytic capacitors for disuse

Mario Snes - Hi, How is this question different than the one you asked 3 years ago? "Question about electrolytic capacitors in electronic devices"

the maximum time interval would be to have it continuously enegized ... did you mean to say minimum?

Personally, I'd just slap the device across the power source and if any caps pop, replace them. I have old electronics, some of which has not been powered in a very long time, and have never seen a reasonably modern (1980+) capacitor blow at power-on.
If you want to be more cautious, use a variac and bring the voltage up slowly over 30-60 minutes, maybe 5% every few minutes.
The recommended methods for reforming involve removing the capacitor from the circuit and using a variable power supply and series resistor, and it seem to me that if you're going to do that you may as well replace the part since the parts are so cheap compared to labo[u]r.

I have electronic devices with aluminum electrolytic capacitors and manufactured in the early 90s and early 2000s and store my home at a temperature of 33-36C, humidity 57-67% and energized devices at 220v AC 60hz if I energize these devices for 1 hour (60 minutes) what is the time interval to energize them again and prevent failures in the aluminum electrolytic capacitors caused by disuse?
I have CRT TVs 29" Philco and Toshiba, consoles Snes JR, Snes Fat, PS2 Slim 90000, power supply 5v and 12v, tvbox T95 Max Plus, DVD Drive Sata internal
